# Is there a division-by-zero problem when we divide by pure imaginary numbers?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, divisibility

I was wondering, if $\frac{x}{0}$ is undefined, is $\frac{x}{i}$ undefined too?

Considering that the real part of $i$ is zero, is the $\frac{x}{0+i}$ some form of division $x$ by $0$?

Does $\frac{x}{0+i}$ cause any problem of the kind $\frac{x}{0}$ does?

Comment: No, $i$ is invertible and its inverse is $-i$ because $-i^2 = 1$. So $\frac{x}{i} = -xi$.

Comment: Not any more than $\frac{x}{0+2}$.

Comment: No because $i$ has a multiplicative inverse namely $-i$ but $0$ doesn't.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is a field, so every non-zero element (also $i$) has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Nope... Not at all.  $0+i \ne 0$ so $\frac {x}{0 + i}$ is no more a problem than $\frac {x}{0 + 1}$ is.  In fact $\frac 1i = -i$ so $\frac x{i} = -xi$.

Comment: "Considering that the real part of i is zero" Doesn't matter.  The *imaginary* part of $i$ is *not* zero.  Division by zero is only a problem with numbers where *both* the real and imaginary part is $0$. And there is only one such number... that number is $0$.  All other numbers are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that complex numbers of the form $a+bi$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers) include all the real numbers ($b=0$) and all the purely imaginary numbers ($a=0$). (This also means that $0$ is the only number that is both real *and* imaginary.)

Any complex number of the form $a+bi$ except for $0$ has a multiplicative inverse (in other words, its reciprocal exists) and therefore dividing by that number is the same as multiplying by the inverse.

Here is an elementary proof for how to explicitly find the multiplicative inverse of $a+bi$:

$$
\frac{1}{a+bi} \frac{a-bi}{a-bi} = \frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}
$$
Notice that by multiplying the top and bottom of the fraction by the same $a-bi$ expression (this is known as the **conjugate** of $a+bi$), the denominator now becomes a simple real number, which you can distribute through the $a-bi$ on the top.

This trick doesn't work on $0$ though, as its conjugate $a-bi$ is still $0$, so you would be multiplying your fraction by $ \frac{0}{0}$, which is clearly illegal!

Answer (score 0):

If $c\ne 0$ and $mn = c\ne$ then $\frac cm = n$ with no error.

If $m=0$ then $mn =0\cdot n = c\ne 0$ will *never* happen. So $\frac cm$ is an error.

But if $Re(m) =0$ .... so what?  There's no reason that that will cause $mn =c$ to be a problem.

Cosider $a + bi$  then $(a + bi)*i = ai + bi^2 = ai +b(-1) = -b + ai$ .  So $\frac {-b+ai}i = a+ bi$ is a perfectly acceptable and reasonable result.

But $Re(i) = 0$.... well, so what?  That in no way forces $w*i$ to be equal to $0$.  So if $w*i = x$ and $x\ne 0$ there is *NOTHING* wrong with saying $w = \frac xi$.

.....

In fact....... $(-i)i = -(i*i) =-(i^2) = -(-1) = 1$  So $-i = \frac 1i$.

So If we ever have a $\frac xi$ that is: $\frac xi = -xi$